# Get a List of All settings for Google Groups

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups-api

I'm curious if there is a way to get a list of ALL settings available for Google Groups. I am currently using the Groups Settings API to get the settings, but the returned JSON/XML resources are lacking many settings available such as:

- Approve Members
- Ban Users
- Approve Messages
- Post Announcements
- etc.

These settings can be found in the Group settings. How do I retrieve these settings via API?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to check the Groups Audit Activity Events using [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/groups)?

Comment: Thanks @jess, however, the Reports API lists all the group changes made by the actors. It's mainly for auditing purpose and is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help your issue :(